# How to make a column not null, and yet it does need to be null when first created

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, `tableA` and `tableB`.

```
tableA(id, tableB_id)

tableB(id, tableA_id)
```

When a record is created in `tableA`, the FK value for `tableB_id` is not yet known.  So I have no choice except for it to be nullable.

But right after it is created, then the row in `tableB` is populated, and then the row in `tableA` is updated.

After this happens, however, I want to ensure that `tableA.tableB_Id` is never null (for data consistency).

Is there some way to ensure this?

My first attempt was to make `tableA.tableB`_id not null, but this prevents records from being create in `tableA`.

The only idea I have been able to come up with is creating another column:

```
tableA.is_initialized
```

Then when `tableA.tableB_id` is populated, set `tableA.is_initialized` to true.

Then add a constraint so that if `is_initialized` is true, then `tableB_Id` must not be null.

Am I on the right track?

To be more specific about the data model: it is a one to many relationship between tableA and tableB.  But I need to know which one of related tableB records is the `default` one (the one currently in use), so I am storing it in tableA. Maybe there is a better way of modeling this in the database, but so far it has worked fine.

Comment: Does MSSQL have deferred foreign key checks?

Comment: At this time MSSQL does not support deferred foreign key checks

Comment: @GregGum . . . If the creation of the `B` value occurs that quickly, then you should insert the `B` record first and then insert the `A` record.  That would be the standard way of handling this.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I have tried, but B also has a FK to A, so it's the same situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a third table:

```
tableA(id, …other data…)                -- no tableB_id
tableB(id, tableA_id, …other data…)
tableA_default_B(tableA_id, tableB_id)
```

Note the absence of `…` in the schema for `tableA_default_B`.  The primary key (unique constraint) on `tableA_default_B` is `tableA_id`.  It is also a foreign key to `tableA`.  The `tableB_id` column is a foreign key to `tableB`.  It presumably could also have a unique constraint on it (since no row in `tableB` is associated with two different rows in `tableA`).

You can then insert into A — no referential constraint to B.  You can insert a record to B with the referential constraint to A.  You can finally insert into `tableA_default_B` with two known IDs.  The problem area will be if there isn't a record in `tableA_default_B` for a given `tableA.id` value — in that case, there shouldn't be a record in `tableB` referencing the entry in `tableA`, except transiently while doing the initial insertion process.  There is, therefore, a small time gap when there is an entry in `tableB` referring to the row in `tableA` without a corresponding entry in `tableA_default_B`, but a transaction around the `INSERT INTO TableB` and `INSERT INTO TableA_Default_B` would fix that.  I would probably create an insert trigger on `tableB` that would insert into `tableA_default_B` if there was no entry in that table for the `tableA_id` used in the just-inserted row in `tableB`.

Enforcing the foreign key constraint with the `is_initialized` flag is perilous, error prone, or not feasible without a trigger.  I'd suggest
not going that route.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is the correct way, and I am going to try implementing this.

Comment: @JonathanLeffer . . . I don't see how this addresses the OP's issue of not having `NULL` values for `A.tableB_id`.  There is no guarantee of a row in the third table.

Comment: The OP seems to think it is OK, @GordonLinoff. There is no `tableB_id` in `tableA` in the revised schema, of course. The code that inserts into `tableB` is probably responsible for also inserting into `tableA_default_B` — whether that's via stored procedure or trigger (best?) or another mechanism (procedural code in the application?) is open to debate. I did identify that there's a small window when there might be a row in `tableB` for a corresponding row in `tableA` with no matching record in `tableA_default_B` — but with a transaction and if code doesn't run with dirty read, it should be OK.

Answer (score 1):

This is an elaboration on Abra's answer.  Your problem is mutual required foreign key relationships.  This is a hard problem to solve.

Your idea of having a second column to "help" the nullability check is a good idea.  The only cumbersome part it that it requires a trigger to really work -- the first time that `A.tableb_id` is set, you want the flag to be set.  I like to avoid triggers if possible.  And, if using a trigger, you don't need another column.  You can just guarantee that `update` never changes the value to `NULL`.

To guarantee non-`NULL` values, we can do something more along Abra's approach, starting with a dummy key in B.  Let's call it `-1`:

```
set identity_insert b on;

insert into b (id)   -- you may want to include other columns
    values (-1);

set identity_insert b off;
```

Then you can structure `A` as:

```
create table A (
    . . . 
    tableB_id int not null default -1 references b(id)
);
```

This does not guarantee that the value cannot be reset to `-1` after it has been set to something else.  To guarantee that, you would need a trigger as described above.

Answer (score 0):

Just a suggestion. Use a dummy ID, say -1 (minus one). So insert that value into table B before inserting into table A. Then each time you insert into table A the value for column tableB_id will be -1. Then you can update later.

Comment: But -1 is not a valid foreign key value, so it cannot be used.

Comment: I said a dummy value and used -1 as a suggestion. Can you think of such a dummy value? Is the idea of using a dummy value worth considering?

Comment: I am waiting for one of the big guns to come along and tell me my data model is messed up and I should be using a separate table to hold the default data.

Answer (score 0):

Use a trigger on insert for table B. When it fires it enters the correct value into table A. That way you ensure the reference is correct in table A when the table B entry exists.